# Помогите сформировать post запрос

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, форма, formdata

Get запрос отрабатывает отлично, а вот пост запрос не получается составить так чтобы он передал в форму 2 поля и вернул json данные с получившейся странички. На данный момент возвращает страничку формы, не понимаю как сделать чтобы заполненная форма отправилась и вернулся результат.

```js
//отрабатывает как надо
let namespace = 'liftsService';
    let options = {
        method: "GET",
        path: "/*****/api/Tag/code/****/value/null/" + id
    };
    ms.request.call(that, { type: 'proxy', namespace: namespace, options: options }, function (result) {
        if (result.error == undefined) {
            generationURL(result.value);
        } else {
            console.error(result.error);
            cb({ "error": "getProjectFromLiftsService:" + result.error });
        }
    });


  // тут проблема 
    function generationURL(name) {
        var formData = new FormData();
            formData.append('where', name);
            formData.append('f', "pjson");

        let namespace = 'arcgis';
        let options = {
            method: "POST",
            path: "/***/rest/services/SVN/*****/****/0/query?where=P_NAME='",
            body: formData
        };

        ms.request.call(that, { type: 'proxy', namespace: namespace, options: options }, function (result) {
            if (result.error == undefined) {
                if (result != null) {
                    contour = result;
                    allContour = getContourPutInArray(contour);
                } else {
                    contour = errorTextModule('Kонтур поднятия не может быть получен', 'Пришёл пустой массив ', null);
                }
            } else {
                console.error(result.error);
                errorTextModule('Ошибка при получении с сервиса ', result.error, null);
                cb({ "error": "getProjectFromArcgis:" + result.error });
            }
        });
    }
```

```js
ms.on('proxy', function (req, cb) {
    let server = '';
    if (req.namespace) {
        //Если указано постранство имен то оно должно быть зарегистрировано
        if (namespaces[req.namespace]) {
            server = namespaces[req.namespace];
        } else {
            cb({ "error": "Не указано пространство имен" });
            return;
        }
    }

    if (!this.token) {
        cb({ "error": "Отсутствует токен кореляции" });
        return;
    }
    const options = req.options || { method: 'GET' };

    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = {};
    }

    options.headers['Correlation-Token'] = this.token;
    options.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';

    if (options.path) {
        options.path = encodeURI(options.path);
    }

    let postData = null;
    if (req.params && (options.method == 'POST')) {
        postData = JSON.stringify(req.params);
        options.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
        options.headers['Content-Length'] = Buffer.byteLength(postData);
    }

    const request = http.request(server, options, (res) => {
        let data = '';
        res.setEncoding('utf8');
        res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', () => {
            if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
                cb({ "error": data, "status": res.statusCode });
            } else {
                try {
                    cb(JSON.parse(data));
                } catch (e) {
                    cb(data);
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: В `Node.js` библиотеки `http` и `https` имеют функцию `request`, но у неё не такой интерфейс какой используется в вашем примере. Не соизволите ли подсказать что это вы такое используете в виде `ms.request`?

Comment: Дорогой @vihtor! http, добавил этот метод

Comment: не понимаю, что вы имеете в виду. смотрю в документацию Node.js и немогу понять, что это за аргумент такой `{ type: 'proxy', namespace: namespace, options: options }`?! Ткните, пожалуйста, носом в документацию к этому методу.